# Can consoles be controlled by programming languages?

Tags: python, vba, console

On the computer management console, there is a local user & group folder. I understand that we can add or remove members from a certain group through that console.

My question is, is it possible to do the stated action without using the console, that is by a programming language?

I'm currently familiar with Python and VBA.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output

Answer (score 0):

Yes!
This is possible.
Microsoft has implemented a powerful scripting language called Powershell which is based on VBscript and the standard CMD syntax for this.

To access the Integrated Scripting Enviroment, press the Windows key + X at the same time, and click the Powershell button in the dialog that appears.

There is a ton of documentation in the manpages.

For more info: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx

If you're a sysadmin (like me) it is imperative you learn how to use it, as Microsoft is phasing out the GUI for Powershell automation step by step, and you'll NEED to know this, saves you so much work.